# Why are multiple entries of 'color' css attribute active in Safari Dev Tools?

Tags: css, safari-web-inspector

Sometimes I see two entries for the CSS 'color' attribute active on a single element, even when one has !important. The one without !important is taking precedence though, as it should (I am trying to force the element to color: white). See screenshot:

[image]

Thanks!

UPDATE: added html markup

```
<div class="x-button x-button-back x-layout-box-item x-stretched" id="quit-button" style="width: auto !important;">
  <span class="x-badge" style="display: none;"></span>
  <span class="x-button-icon x-hidden" id="ext-element-1109"></span>
  <span class="x-button-label" style="" id="ext-element-1110">Quit</span>
</div>
```

.peacekeepers-edition is set on the first element inside the body, #playview is a distant descendent.

Comment: can we see the html?   your CSS rules aren't the same there.  one is more "precise" than the other.

Comment: I would guess the `!important` rule is targeting an ancestor whilst the other rule is targeting the element itself (Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bgboef8n/1/). Hard to say without any code

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Nope, the matched selector: .peacekeepers-edition is in both rules

Comment: Yes, and `.peacekeepers-edition` is an ancestor in both rules. What's your point?

Comment: Ancestor? Looks like a direct matched selector. Some live code would help

Comment: `color: #ccccff` is applied to an element with class `.x-button-icon` whilst the `color: #fff !important` is applied to an ancestor with class `x-button`

Comment: @Mircea then you are looking at different code to me

Comment: I added the markup so you could see it. Both rules apply directly to the element in question, but each to a different class; .x-button, and .x-button-back. I already marked an answer to this question, but for the purposes of this comment thread I suppose I would like to know why the !important rule didn't take precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the specificity of the rule all proprieties from the CSSOM will appear in the inspector rule view. The fact that the "color:#ccffff" is not crossed/underline is just an inspector bug.

BTW, you overqualified your selectors: `.preacekeepers-edition #playview` will have a specificity of 1|1|0|, that is way more that you should have. Adding !important will make things hard to manage later.

Comment: I marked this as an answer since it answers the question most directly, which is concerning that both elements are active in the Safari inspector. Man, Safari's dev tools have so many bugs!

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions about your markup (because you haven't provided any), but I think it's fairly safe to say that this is your issue.

Assuming your markup is something like this...

```
<div class="peace-keepers-edition">
    <div id="playview">
        <button class="x-button-back">
            <i class="x-button-icon">icon</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your first selector targets the button element...

```
.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

but your second selector targets an element that is a descendant of your button...

```
.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back .x-button-icon {
    color: #ccccff;
}
```

Your `!important` rule is irrelevant because your selectors are targeting different elements.

Easy fix; add this line after line `769`...

```
.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back .x-button-icon {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Broken example...

```css
body {
    background: #1a1a1a;
}
button {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: green;
}

.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back {
    color: #FFF !important;
}

.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back .x-button-icon {
    color: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<div class="peace-keepers-edition">
    <div id="playview">
        <button class="x-button-back">
            <i class="x-button-icon">icon</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example...

```css
body {
    background: #1a1a1a;
}
button {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: green;
}

.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back {
    color: #FFF !important;
}

.peace-keepers-edition #playview .x-button-back .x-button-icon {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="peace-keepers-edition">
    <div id="playview">
        <button class="x-button-back">
            <i class="x-button-icon">icon</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I updated the question with markup so you can see that both rules are targeting the same element since it is .x-button.x-button-back. Very strange.

Comment: They aren't targeting the same element. `x-button-icon` is a _child_ of `x.button `

Comment: Ah, right you are. Sorry for the confusion. So a normal attribute on the exact element trumps an !important attribute on a parent element? Is that what Mircea was talking about with a specificity of 1|1|0?